# Какую скрытую информацию содержат файлы jpg/jpeg?

Tags: jpeg

Есть ли в файлах изображений какие-то скрытые мета-теги, в которых может быть информация об авторе файла, дате создания или фотоаппарате, на который они сделаны. А то что-то такое слышал, а нагуглить ничего не удалось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта скрытая информация имеет свое вполне определенное имя - [EXIF](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXIF). Начните чтение с чтения википедии, а потом, если нужно, [официальную спецификацию](http://www.exif.org/specifications.html).

Answer (score 2):

Эту информацию можно посмотреть через свойства файла в Проводнике Windows. А ещё лучше - в ACDSee